# Regular expression to validate InetSocketAddresses (ipv4/v6 + port addresses)

Tags: java, regex, ipv6, ipv4, port-number

I am looking for **tested** regular expressions for both ipv4 and ipv6 [InetSocketAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#toString%28%29) (i.e., ip address + port number). I am not interested in validating hostnames.

It can be two regex (one for ipv4, one for ipv6) or one combined regex.

Does anyone have any to share?

**EDIT**

For ip4 format information see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html#format), for ipv6 format information see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html#format). Then, port number is added with ':'.

**EDIT 2**
To create a string representation, I will proceed like this:

```
byte[] tmp = { 10, 1, 0, 0 };
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(
        InetAddress.getByAddress(tmp), 443);
```

which returns:

```
/10.1.0.0:443
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to match? I am assuming you mean you want any of the following to match: `192.168.0.1:443`, `192.168.0.1`, `[2001:db8::1]:443`, and `2001:db8::1` to all produce matches. I ask because `InetSocketAddress` takes the port in a separate constructor parameter. I guess you'd want a regex with groups to pull that out separately, if it exists. So you might up with 4 regular expressions depending on if you've got an address alone, or an address with a port.

Comment: Anything generated by InetSocketAddress.toString(). I would like to check and recreate the ISA by parsing those strings. REM: ISAs always have a port.

Comment: @JVerstry, thanks; it would be helpful if you update your question to provide some sample output from `.toString()` that you need to match against. (I guess it would be best to make sure to include both link-local and global unicast IPv6 addresses, so you can make sure you cover cases with scope zone) That said, I am not sure if it's best to rely on `.toString()`; is that guaranteed to be consistent across all Java platforms and versions?

Comment: @Mike I have added format links in the question. I believe it will be consistent across Java platforms.

Comment: @JVerstry, I do not think your updates are correct. I just tried a test case where I constructed a `new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("10.1"), 443);` and the `.toString()` was `/10.0.0.1:443`. If you are running a regex on the `.toString()` I don't think you'll need to worry about (for example) an IPv4 address in a non-normalized `x.x` format, for example. This is on Java version `1.6.0_21-b07` on Windows.

Comment: FYI, `.toString()` for `new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("2001:db8::1"), 443)` returns `/2001:db8:0:0:0:0:0:1:443`. (ugly; I have to assume they will clean that up, since that is not the recommended way to print IPv6 addresses)

Comment: Here's a third example: `new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("fe80::1%22"), 443)`'s `.toString()` returns `/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%22:443`.

Comment: @Mike I have updated the question again, but may be this situation is unsolvable, because we don't know enough about Java's behavior in this case (i.e., too unpredictable).

Comment: I need to store Ipv4/6 + port number addresses into string format. I have implemented a solution where I retrieve the byte[] and convert it with base 64. Then I append '_' and the port number. The reverse operation is easy. I was hoping that a regex solution was possible...

Comment: @JVerstry why not print the string as a [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) instead, which would be a much more standardized format?

Comment: @Mike Because I did not think about it... lol. Create an answer if you want to get the points...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to use a regex on the `.toString()` of `InetSocketAddress` to do this might not be such a good idea. (see comments on question above)

One possible alternative is to use a [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) or [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to print the address in string format, which is [much more standardized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

---

**Edit:**

On the other hand, if you want to torture yourself with regular expressions... ;-)

IPv4:

```
      Pattern: .*/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+):([0-9]+)
Java constant: ".*/([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+):([0-9]+)"
```

Handles only dotted-quad format addresses. Does not detect invalid addresses.

IPv6:

```
      Pattern: .*/([0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+(%[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?):([0-9]+)
Java constant: ".*/([0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+(%[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?):([0-9]+)"
```

Handles IPv6-addresses with all 8 16-bit sections. (note again that the only reason this works is because the Inet6Address implementation in Java seems to print the addresses in a non-standard way - probably so it can append the port number and there is no ambiguity) Does not detect invalid IPv6 addresses. Handles only lowercase hex characters. Handles zone/scope IDs (if present) with uppercase or lowercase letters and/or digits.

I tested them with a [handy applet I found](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ematuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html).

And for the record, I still think it's a bad idea. ;-) I can't be sure if all Java platforms will print the addresses this way.

Comment: Thanks. For the records, I have used URIs, since URLs don't accept the 'tcp' schema/protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the [Regular Expression Library](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=ipv6)

Comment: Did you look at the link? It lists a few regex, network addresses included.

Comment: For example, IPv6: `^([0-9a-fA-F]{4}|0)(\:([0-9a-fA-F]{4}|0)){7}$`. IPv4 *and* IPv6: `([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}`. And other variations.

Comment: @Santa yes I did take a look at the link, but where do these take port numbers into account (i.e., did you read the question fully)? Moreover, there are non-matching values which should and vice-versa. These regex are buggy.. They don't answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea.  IPv6 addresses in [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952) form aren't a regular language, so parsing them with a regular expression is the road to failure.  Use the proper parsing function, e.g. the POSIX `inet_pton` function.  Java should have one somewhere.  Who knows, it might even be smart enough to handle IPv6 addresses with embedded IPv4 subfields according to section 5 of RFC 5952.

Seriously... don't use regular expressions for this.

Comment: `inet_pton()` is the eqivalent of `InetAddress.getByName()`. Java figures everything out for you. The only reason the regular expressions I posted even work is because of the strange way that InetAddress *does* print the address (incorrectly, I imagine) in a regular fashion. For example, `new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("fe80::192.168.0.1%22"), 443)` returns `/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1%22:443`