# Regex to determine, if IPv6 or IPv4 and if port is given

Tags: php, regex, ipv6, ipv4

I'm searching for a regular expression that can determine, if the given **IP address** is `IPv4` or `IPv6` and (most important for me) if a port number is attached, or not.

I tried a few regular expressions, but none of them worked as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747548/regular-expression-to-validate-inetsocketaddresses-ipv4-v6-port-addresses

Comment: I saw that, but that didn't solve my problem. It's not required to determine the ip type, but without knowledge about the type, i can't determine, if it has a port or not.

Comment: Well, at least give us a list of valid and unvalid input, with your expected ouput...

Comment: It's very helpful if, when you have a solution that you have tried but does NOT work, if you tell us what it is so that we know what you have looked at already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can assume that the input will be a simple valid IP address and you simply want to know whether you have a port or not, you could do the following:

```
if (preg_match("/^(?:[0-9.]+|(?:\[[0-9a-fA-F:]+\]))(:[0-9]+)$/", $ip)) 
{
    echo "A port was found.";
} 
else 
{
    echo "A port was not found.";
}
```

This will match an IP adress like

- `[2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344]:8080` or
- `127.0.0.1:8080`

but it will not match

- `2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344` or
- `127.0.0.1`

Keep in mind that [the standard defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) an IPv6 host to be distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets.

Comment: Fails to recognize the optional zone identifier in IPv6 literals, c.f. [RFC 6874](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6874). Also fails to recognize IPv6 addresses with upper-case letter hexadecimal digits.

Comment: As long as the author doesn't provide more information about valid in/outputs, I had to make several assumptions. Therefore my answer is based on _simple_ addresses unless otherwise requested. I've added the uppercase digits though :)

Comment: Basicly, that's exactly, what i'm looking for, ty ;) Further suggestions are appreciated, but for now, this is enough :)

Comment: @Fabian: The standard you are referring to only describes IP address representation in URIs. The questioner did not specify if the address s/he wants to find appears in a URI. In general, an IPv6 address does not need to be written in square brackets.

Comment: @Dubu: You are totally correct. However I did assume that if s/he has a string representing an IP address incl. port, that this usually is an URI. Without the brackets, I don't see any possibility to clearly identify the port from other IPv6 parts - that's what the brackets have been introduced for in the standard.