# How to remove port number from IP address and ipv6 with PHP?

Tags: php

I was using `strstr( $ip, ':') === false ? $ip : strstr( $ip, ':', true);` but this of course doesn't work with ipv6 so I would know if there is a cleaner way of checking if port it's provided and remove it in PHP.

So for:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1:3233
2001:569:be89:6200:5da6:745a:84fe:d899:3423
```

I get:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1
2001:569:be89:6200:5da6:745a:84fe:d899
```

Comment: This feels similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275221/regex-to-determine-if-ipv6-or-ipv4-and-if-port-is-given ... specifically that the IPV6 spec dictates the IP needs to be wrapped in `[` and `]` if using a port

Comment: Wouldn't splitting the IP by `:` and popping off the last `:` and anything after it do it?

Comment: Please share more details - what keeps you from checking first whether this is a v4 or v6 address?

Comment: Nothing, I just receive an IP, I don't know if will be v4 or v6 and if they will include port or not. But if they include I need to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url(, PHP_URL_HOST)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$arr = [
    '192.168.0.1',
    '192.168.0.1:3233',
    '2001:569:be89:6200:5da6:745a:84fe:d899:3423',
    '[2001:db8::1]:8080'
];

print_r(array_map(fn($v) => parse_url('http://'.$v, PHP_URL_HOST), $arr));
```

Result would be all hosts, without ports

```
Array
(
    [0] => 192.168.0.1
    [1] => 192.168.0.1
    [2] => 2001:569:be89:6200:5da6:745a:84fe:d899
    [3] => [2001:db8::1]
)
```

Comment: Actually it's not working. For example if you test it with '2001:569:be89:6200:8936:7907:fcf1:961b' it will strip out last part which is not a port

Answer (score -1):

Actually I ended up using this, which is not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
if ( strpos( $ip, ':') !== false ) {
    // ipv6
    if( count( explode(':', $ip ) ) > 2 && strpos( $ip, '[') !== false ) 
        $ip = parse_url('http://'.$ip, PHP_URL_HOST);
    elseif( count( explode(':', $ip ) ) === 2 ) 
        $ip = strstr( $ip, ':', true );
}
```

Note that [the answer from @lawrence-cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805163) *is not working* with IP `2001:569:be89:6200:8936:7907:fcf1:961b`.